# What do "visa notification letter" and "official media letter" mean regarding a Chinese visa?

Tags: visas, china

On the website for the Chinese Embassy in the US, the steps for getting an L visa listed [here](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/hrsq/#L) include the following note:

> The Visa Notification Letter and the official media letter may be in
>   the form of fax, photocopy or computer printout.

What is this referring to? I think that "Visa Notification Letter" is if you were invited to China by some official agency, but I'm not sure about "official media letter."

Comment: The site is down. Cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:u2XQ_2z3T1sJ:www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/hrsq/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: A .org embassy site that is down? That sounded very suspicious. But I just checked and it is a legitimate link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It refers to:

> Visa Notification Letter issued by the Information Department of the
>   Ministry of Foreign Affairs of China and an official letter issued by
>   the media organization for which the journalist works.

for J1 and J2 visa.

You quoted just the "Notes", which explain the rules above of the notes, and in the rules above (for L visa) there is "Visa Notification Letter". So this note just explain in what form/manner it should be sent it.  The note you copied is generic, and copied verbatim various times thru the page, for different visas.

Personally, I don't exclude that for media people could apply for visa L in certain circumstances. Maybe for travel/nature photographers (e.g. National Geographic), which are a mix of tourists and journalist.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the "Note:3" section under the L visa category is simply a typo.  There is no "Visa Notification Letter" nor "official media letter" required for an L visa.  Whomever was creating the content for that webpage copied and pasted rather than typing a bit about what form your itinerary could be provided in.